# suppressing messages while running sql queries in a script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, scripting, sqlplus

I am trying to write a simple query-script that gets me cnt of rows in a table. However I am facing problem to suppress all sorts of oracle messages. All I am interested is the output:

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sqlplus /nolog <<EOF
connect user/pswd@databse
set serveroutput on
set heading off
set feedback off
select count(*) from table;
exit;
EOF
```

My output looks like this:

```
.desktop% sh sql.ksh 
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Dec 7 12:00:42 2010
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.
SQL> Connected.
SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> 
        70
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

All I want is the number 70 without any message so that I can write it to logs etc regularly. I know I can parse for the number but I ll have to change that every time my query or schema changes. Can't I just ask mysqlplus to suppress all those messages?

Answer (score 12):

You have to add the uppercase `S` option to `sqlplus`.

The help message (of sqlplus that comes with Oracle 11.2.0.4.0) specifies:

> ```
> -S    Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
>       the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
>       commands.
> ```

With something like

```
$ sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
connect user/pswd@databse
set serveroutput on
set heading off
set feedback off
exec package.procedure($1); -- procedure that calls DBMS_OUTPUT procedures ...
select 2 from dual;
-- ...
exit;
EOF
```

you only get the output from the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer and the results from select statements.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use sqlplus -s for silent mode

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect user/pswd@databse
set serveroutput on
set heading off
set feedback off
select count(*) from table;
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: I agree that by adding -s there is no any messages even those that i want to see. The question is how to hide all these messages and to display only messages that i would like to see, for example if i add  
dbms_output.put_line('Hello Word')
I would like to see Hello Word only. HOW CAN I DO THAT???

Comment: @vogash, see my answer for details

Answer (score 4):

Try the `-s` flag. e.g.,

```
sqlplus /s /nolog <<EOF
```

...